# Music doesn't work in my codding. What's the wrong?

Tags: html, audio

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>

<audio autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="sound.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

ıt seems that work at W3school but i couldn't make it in my browser. I tried it chrome and firefox but it doesn't work. What's the wrong? I'm new about codding

Comment: Read this - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to put

```
<audio controls autoplay>
```

instead of

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it doesn't play auto. I mean i should click button to play. And i dont want to see player bar. It should be hidden

Comment: To make it hidden you can put: style="display:none;"